# Search column not working in the Google Spreadsheet script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet with different columns and I've put as variable in my code `var COLUMN_URL = 10 ;`so now I would like to change in order to search the column URL which is in the first row of the sheet so I wrote this code :

```
var COLUMN_URL = function find_COLUMN_URL(){
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID);
  var sheet = tss.getSheets()[0];
  var data = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,1).getValues(); 
  for(n=0;n<data.length;++n){ 
    if(data[0][n].toString().match('URL')=='URL')
      return n;
  }
}
```

and I deleted the `var COLUMN_URL = 10` but when I execute the code as I did with the previous declaration in the main fonction I doesn't work .Do you have an idea why is not working?Thank you.

Edit: I've changed in a different version like this :

```js
function find_column_projet(){
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID);
  var sheet = tss.getSheets()[0];
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn() + 1;
  var data = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,lastColumn).getValues(); 
  for(n=0;n<data.length;n++){ 
 if(data[0][n].toString().match('URL')=='URL')
      COLUMN_URL = n + 1 ;
}

function show_URL(){
  find_column_projet();
   Logger.log('The URL  ' + COLUMN_URL);
   
}
```

and in the log I have URL undefined and I don't get it where is the problem.I want to recuperate the first row and search for the URL and then return the number of the column.

Comment: Of course there are no values in the column that is to the right of the last column with values in it...

Comment: Thanks so to correct the code is var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn() no? in this way I will get the values in my first row var data = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,lastColumn).getValues();  if i understood.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have forgotten to store the value returned by the find_column_projet() function, in the second version of your code:

```
function show_URL(){
  var COLUMN_URL = find_column_projet();
   Logger.log('The URL  ' + COLUMN_URL);

}
```

The first iteration of your code is assigning COLUMN_URL to the function itself:

```
var COLUMN_URL = function find_COLUMN_URL(){
//...
}
```

when these operations should be separate:

```
function find_COLUMN_URL(){
}

var COLUMN_URL = find_COLUMN_URL();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!I used finally the second code and  i have >>> The URL  undefined the problem i think i'm not sure^^^^ comes from the fact that I know that  getRange is long in time and I want only the firts row with headers that i have and i do  var data = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,lastColumn).getValues();  but if i do  var data = sheet.getRange(1,1,lastColumn,lastColumn).getValues(); in this case the URL colum is 10 and i don't get it why with the first one it doesn't work because i will be more efficently